# Django сервер зависает с ngrok

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

У меня есть сайт на django и я запустил его с ngrok. Сайт начал после некоторых действий с формой отключаться, пока не нажать ctrl+c после чего он выдает следующее

```
[07/Jan/2024 23:53:53,268] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 49751)
```

Если нужны настройки settings.py то вот

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.ngrok.io', '.ngrok-free.app']
INTERNAL_IPS = ["*"]
```

Сам сайт подключается и работает нормально, просто его выбивает периодически так. Он на обновлении зависает и так до timeoutа